# Windows 7 Notepad using Terminal 6 font shrinks line font with grave character

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts, notepad

I use Terminal 6 Regular in Notepad. Under Windows 7, if the line of text contains a grave character, Notepad displays the line in a much smaller font. The character I am referring to is on the upper right of the US keyboard layout, between the Esc and Tab keys, (`), ASCII code 96 decimal.

I have experienced this on several installations of Windows 7, various editions, various 32/64 bit versions, on various computer hardware at two different employers and my home.

This does not happen for any of the other sizes of Terminal that are available from Notepad, nor other randomly selected fonts or sizes, including a couple of other bitmapped fonts in .FON file format, Sheldon and ProFont.

This does not happen in Windows XP. I do not know if Windows Vista or 8 are affected.

If I set the Font Style in Notepad for Terminal 6 to Regular or Bold, any line with a grave character is much smaller. If I set the Font Style to Oblique or Bold Oblique, the text displays normally. Unfortunately, it is also slanted, as expected with Oblique, so it is not as readable.

Turning ClearType on or off does not affect this behavior, although with ClearType on, the tiny font that is used to render lines with a grave character becomes so faint and fuzzy that there is no hope of reading them.

This is not just a bug of Notepad, but of the Windows text box control. A custom VB6 program with three text boxes, each containing some text with a grave in the middle, display normally for the text boxes that use MS Sans Serif 9 and Terminal 9, but smaller for the text box using Terminal 6.

Is anybody else having this problem? I can't find mention of this problem with a web search. Any suggestions? The obvious suggestion is, "Use a different font or size," but I like the density and clarity of text that Terminal 6 offers.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a surprise when I pulled out a VB6 app I wrote under XP to use it under Seven.
The app has textboxes with the Terminal font, size 9.

The text appears narrowed under W7.

Playing around with the properties of this font using a dedicated test app showed that size 6 appears no different with bold typeface than with normal typeface in either WXP or W7. The other sizes behave correctly, though.

I would say that this font has a problem and should not be used. Too bad.